# Within the number of different ways to order in line the letters of the word NOVATOLOGY, in how many ways G and N are not successive?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Within the number of different ways to order in line the letters of the word NOVATOLOGY, in how many ways G and N are not successive?
I was thinking - let's put aside N and G. There are $\frac{8!}{3!}$ different ways to order in line the rest of the letters (because O repeats 3 times).
Now, let's find how many ways there are to place N and G in between the letters (there are 9 gaps between the letters _O_V_A_T_O_L_O_Y_) - so I get $\frac{9!}{7!}$ ways.
Multiply and the answer is $\frac{8!}{3!}\cdot\frac{9!}{7!} = \frac{8!}{3\cdot2}\cdot9\cdot8=8!\cdot3\cdot4=8!\cdot12$
Am I right?

Comment: Sounds good. An alternate approach would be to take the $\frac{10!}{3!}$ total ways if we don't care and subtract the number of ways where you have "GN" as well as the ways you have "NG", being $2\cdot\frac{9!}{3!}$ for a total of $\frac{10!}{3!}-2\cdot\frac{9!}{3!}$, which you can see gives the same answer as yours.  (The number of ways of having "GN" can be counted by considering "GN" as a single letter, say $G\!\!\!_N$ and permuting the 9 characters around for a total of $\frac{9!}{3!}$)

Comment: Nice way  of doing it.